# Can IEnumerable<T> ever be null

Tags: c#-4.0, collections, ienumerable

When called through the `DataContext.ExecuteQuery<T>()` is it possible for return object of type of IEnumerable actually be a null? Not an empty sequence but a null object pointer?

Comment: Isn't it always *possible*? Why not just code defensively and handle nulls gracefully?

Comment: You can't get a warranty for every possible Linq data provider.  But you want to know when it returns null, make sure you crash loudly by not testing for it and not catching NRE.  That's junk code you don't want a dependency on.

Answer (score 0):

[DataContext.ExecuteQuery Method (String, Object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.110).aspx) states it will return ever IEnumerable not null.